# Java progressbar for matlab, how do you feed the values to it?

Tags: swing, matlab, matlab-guide

I came across an interesting alternative to matlab waitbar which is from java, it follows as below.

```
jBarHandle = javax.swing.JProgressBar(0, 103); 
jBarHandle.setStringPainted(true);
jBarHandle.setIndeterminate(false);


posPanel = getpixelposition(handles.slider1,true); 
javacomponent(jBarHandle,posPanel,handles.fig); 
jBarHandle.setValue(fix(0));
```

calling the above code under output function of GUIDE will update the slider with the java enabled one. But how to pass the variable_data into setValue ?

anyone tried this? or have any idea? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the variable directly to the `setValue` method of your `JProgressBar` object. Here I have used [`javaMethodEDT`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javamethodedt.html) to ensure that the method is called from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You could also just call `jBarHandle.setValue(k)` directly.

```
jBarHandle = javax.swing.JProgressBar(0, 103);
jBarHandle.setStringPainted(true);
jBarHandle.setIndeterminate(false);

fig = figure('Position', [0 0 200 20]);
[jhandle, hhandle] = javacomponent(jBarHandle, [0 0 1 1], fig);
set(hhandle, 'parent', fig, 'Units', 'norm', 'Position', [0 0 1 1])

for k = 1:103
    javaMethodEDT('setValue', jBarHandle, k);
    pause(0.1);
end
```

[image]

The value that you pass to the progress bar should just be a variable within your local scope. I'm not completely sure why you're overlaying a slider with this progress bar, but you could link the value of these two by simply doing the following

```
listener = addlistener(handles.slider1, 'Value', 'PostSet', @(s,e)jBarHandle.setValue(e.NewValue));
```

Then whenever the slider value changes (either programmatically or through the GUI), the progress bar gets updated as well.

More info in the EDT [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt) provided by Yair Altman.

If you want to save your java handle within your GUI you can use the following

```
setappdata(handles.fig, 'ProgressBar', jBarHandle);
```

Then from the external function you can retrieve it the following way

```
figure_handle = findall(0, 'type', 'figure', 'tag', 'fig');
jBarHandle = getappdata(figure_handle, 'ProgressBar');
javaMethodEDT('setValue', jBarHandle, value)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to execute "jBarHandle.setValue(k)" from an external function ? I mean I will define bar handle and position insidee the GUIDE GUI .m file, but change the value i,e setValue from an external function (meaning function in  another .m file)?

Comment: @statisticalbeginner just save the java handle within you GUI and then you can access it from elsewhere. `handles.jBar = jBarHandle` or `setappdata(fig, 'jprogress', jBarHandle)` and then from the external function retrieve the handle `jBarHandle = getappdata(gcf, 'jprogress')`

Comment: @statisticalbeginner I have added some code which should be able to make that possible.

Comment: May I know how to take the figure handle into the external function ? (Lets say if my figure has tag "fig")

Comment: `hfigure = findall(0, 'type', 'figure', 'tag', 'fig')`

Comment: sorry I there is some problem . ??? Reference to non-existent field 'jprogress'.
At the external function side.I am passing the hfigure to guidata to get the handles, but no help. Do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104458/discussion-between-suever-and-statisticalbeginner).